# Resizing a C++ double pointer array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to resize a pointer-to-pointer array in C++, however I am running into a segmentation fault after resizing.

My resize code looks like this:

```
CustomClass **arr;
int capacity = 20;
...
void resize(size_t new_capacity) {
    CustomClass** resized_arr = new CustomClass*[new_capacity];

    memcpy(resized_arr, arr, new_capacity * sizeof(CustomClass));

    delete [] arr;

    capacity = new_capacity;

    arr = resized_arr;

    print(); // segmentation fault while printing half way through the hash array

}

void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != NULL) {
            cout << "KEY: " << i << ", VAL: " << arr[i]->to_string() << endl; // the to_string() seg faults
        }
    }
}

string to_string() { return a + " of " + b; } // a and b are strings
```

The print function will print out a handful of the items in the array, and then seg fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying the wrong number of bytes in your `memcpy`, and the new elements need to be initialized to NULL.  Replace the existing `memcpy` call with the following statements:

```
memcpy(resized_arr, arr, capacity * sizeof(*resized_arr));
for (size_t c = capacity; c < new_capacity; ++c)
     resized_arr[c] = nullptr;
```

`capacity` and `new_capacity` should be the same type.  If the new capacity could be smaller than the old one, this will need to be adjusted.

Alternatively, instead of the new `for` loop, you could use

```
memset(&resized_arr[capacity], 0, sizeof(*resized_arr) * (new_capacity - capacity));
```

but this is much easier to get wrong, and has problems if the new capacity is less than the old one.

You could replace the memcpy with

```
for (size_t c = 0; c < capacity; ++c)
    resized_arr[c] = arr[c];
```

to avoid the issues with getting the `memset` wrong.  The compiler, when optimizing, is likely to generate the same code either way.

Comment: The `memcpy` and `memset` caused various errors for me, however the simple `for-loop` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
memcpy(resized_arr, arr, new_capacity * sizeof(CustomClass));
```

it should be:

```
memcpy(resized_arr, arr, new_capacity * sizeof(CustomClass*));
```

Note that you can avoid a lot of unnecessary pain by using e.g. a `std::vector<CustomClass>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CustomClass> >` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: It is unfortunately a requirement that I use and resize an array for this project. I tried using `sizeof(CustomClass*)` but it produces the same seg fault

Comment: I'd use `sizeof(*resized_arr)`, and the new array elements need initialized to NULL.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm using `sizeof(*resized_arr)` appears to be working.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm spotted the other problem -- your larger array has entries at the end that aren't set by the memcpy() call; you'll need to manually initialize them (either with a for-loop or with a memset()) to make sure they are properly NULL and don't contain uninitialized/arbitrary values.

Comment: Wouldn't `memcpy` be copying more bytes than are available at `arr`, since we specify new size as number of bytes to copy?This would be if we use `sizeof(*resized_arr)`.Shouldn't it be `sizeof(*arr)`?

Comment: How would I use `memset` to initialise the new values? By using only `sizeof(*rezied_arr)` the resulting array only has two values, but it should have about 25.

Comment: I'd put a memset(resized_arr, 0, new_capacity * sizeof(CustomClass*)) just before the memcpy() call, myself.  (well, not really -- I'd actually avoid memset() and memcpy() entirely and use a for-loop to set the values using the good old assignment-operator, instead; it's likely to be faster than memcpy()/memset() and it's definitely less error-prone)

Comment: @King: Can you use `std::copy_n`?  It knows the data type being copied, making it much harder to mess up the size

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes I could use `copy_n`

Answer (score 0):

Your `print()` method fails because when you create new array of `CustomClass*` pointers, you do not zero initialize them, and as a result, your check for `nullptr` fails when printing, and you call `to_string()` on invalid pointer.

So first thing is first:

```
CustomClass** resized_arr = new CustomClass*[new_capacity]();
```

Note `()` at the end, this will make sure that all pointers are null. To `memcpy` old array into new you need to know how many bytes to copy, which will be old capacity * bytes in `CustomClass*` pointer, so

```
memcpy(resized_arr, arr, capacity * sizeof(CustomClass*));
```

Here is an example of this working: https://ideone.com/HStRBI